# How to code/edit React Native mobile apps on Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, mobile

**NB:** Not talking about the emulator or env setup, but writing code in Android Studio.

---

I'm a beginner to React Native and I know it seems an easy question, but I'm fed up of searching on it for the last two days without getting an answer for it.

How do we exactly run React-Native apps on Android Studio the same as we do in Flutter? Mainly the edit configuration step is a headache for me. I know we can use command line to run it or VS Code, but I would want to avoid the command line.

Please help...

#### What I have done so far

- Installed React Native CLI globally
- Created an app using React Native
- Setup all environment including env variables and paths for SDK and JDK etc
  Now my app runs on the emulator and physical devices.

#### The Problem

When I open my app in Android Studio it says ADD CONFIGURATION on the top. I don't know how do I add configuration. I tried adding Android App (app). It works and it builds the app when i open the app's Android folder, but not when I do it generally using the Project folder.

Here are some screenshots:

See edit Configuration error:
[image]

Configuration is not set:
[image]

What do i select to run it using android studio debug and run buttons:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Launch Android Studio and open the project**:

1. Launch the Android Studio.
2. Select "Open an existing Android Studio project."
3. Go to the folder containing your React Native project and choose the Android folder.

**Include Configuration**:

1. In the toolbar of Android Studio, you need to notice a dropdown menu labelled "app."
2. if it says "Add Configuration," click on it after clicking on it.

**Put the Run/Debug Configuration in Place**:

1. To add a new configuration, click the "+" button in the Run/Debug Configuration dialogue box.
2. Select "React Native" from the configurations list.

**Within the window for configuring React Native**:

1. Make sure the "Name" is something that describes your app.
2. Put your Node.js interpreter's path in the "Node Interpreter" setting.
3. Your React Native project's root folder should be the "Working Directory" setting.
4. "Command" should be set to run-android.

**Apply and Accept**:

1. To save the configuration, click "Apply" and then "OK".
2. Return to the "app" choice in the toolbar dropdown.
3. Choose the configuration that you just made (either the one you named it or your app name).
4. In Android Studio, click the green "Run" or "Debug" buttons to build and launch your React Native application.
5. With the provided settings, Android Studio should now create and launch your React Native application. This should to offer a substitute for executing your application via the command line.

**Choose Configuration and Execute**:

1. Return to the "app" choice in the toolbar dropdown.
2. Choose the configuration that you just made (either the one you named it or your app name).
3. In Android Studio, click the green "Run" or "Debug" buttons to build and launch your React Native application.

Comment: Hi pratik, thanks for your help, in  Run/Debug Configuration List i dont see react native. can you please help me with that.